# Parser for M3U file with EXTINF tag with attributes

Tags: java, android, m3u

I am working in android(java) and need to parse m3u file having attribute(key=value pairs). I found parser for simple format of EXTINF but I cant find any for latest format. 
Sample file can be seen in this [link](http://ss-iptv.com/en/users/18-about-m3u).
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide an example of that format you want to parse.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823429/parser-m3u-file-using-java-in-android-studio