# parser m3u file using java in android studio

Tags: java, android, streaming, m3u

i am looking to parser m3u file in java. channel name then its link I've googled for this but unable to find solution.
m3u file looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,VIP AR: Bein Max 1 HD
http://portal.onlineiptv.net:5210/live/Jyw2SMYjxe/9589.ts
#EXTINF:-1,VIP AR: Bein Max 2 HD
http://portal.onlineiptv.net:5210/live/Jyw2SMYjxe/9590.ts
#EXTINF:-1,VIP AR: Bein Max 3 HD
http://portal.onlineiptv.net:5210/live/Jyw2SMYjxe/9591.ts
```

i want to show the details  like  this:

```
ChannelCategory - ChannelName
Url of that channel
```

> i have a working code but in that i'm unable to fetch channels links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse M3U file in C# using Regular expressions & in Java you can do same Or create custom  Parser.

https://github.com/sajjad0321/iptv

Comment: @Sjjad Jave can i use Remote m3u url instead of local file to parse m3u using your code ? How to call the parse function ?

Comment: @user1788736 **Not yet**. i'm trying to achieve it. "If u can do?". For now i'm downloading the file then Parsing it in my App.

Answer (score 1):

java m3u parser - [SimpleM3UParser](https://github.com/gsantner/opoc/blob/master/java/java/net/gsantner/opoc/format/playlist/SimpleM3UParser.java)

```
ArrayList<SimpleM3UParser.M3U_Entry> mParser = new SimpleM3UParser().parse("http://....m3u");

  for(int i=0; i < mParser.size(); i++){
         mParser.get(i).getName();
         mParser.get(i).getUrl();
         //.... etc
     }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).